# ng-controller not passing value to view

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ngmodel

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div ng-app="myapp1">
<div ng-controller="cont1">
    <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myapp1', []).controller('cont1', function($scope){
$scope.data = "{message: 'Hello!'}";
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I am passing values from a controller 'cont1' to the view of 'myapp1' module. I should see the result as "Hello!" on a html page, but I am getting pure blank white page. Can someone help me out?

Comment: $scope.data = {message: 'Hello!'};

Comment: Torres. What else must I add dear? I think value is stored as data.message which I am retrieving in {{data.message}} in appropriate module "myapp1"

Comment: thats all what u need if you linked .js files correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing wrong is

```
$scope.data = "{message: 'Hello!'}";
```

should be

```
$scope.data = {message: 'Hello!'};
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/txo3z7xu/)

Comment: O boye! That worked. Those double quotes created real problem. done man, thanks!

Comment: Love u dear ! :) - I was looking of your emailid dear. I dont know if I can see it at your profile .. thanks buddy! u r awesome ... answer! simple & short!

Comment: U r good! Might need some tips recently. I am new to angular buddy! ;)

Comment: try to solve the issue yourself. Lot of resource available online.Still if u get stuck post your Issue on StackOverFlow and some one will help :)

Comment: :) .. thanx dear for support !

Answer (score 0):

please don used ("") when you insert object to scope :).change like this:

```js
 
$scope.data = {message: 'Hello!'};
```

Comment: Thanks arip. Got it dear! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Format your data correctly:

```js
angular.module('myapp1', [])
 .controller('cont1', function($scope){
   $scope.data = {message: 'Hello!'};
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp1">
  <div ng-controller="cont1">
    <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```